# How to change Navigation and on hover tooltip background color in one page website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used a scroll navigation bar in my one page site.
If you see in snippet Nav dot and on hover tool tip in black background color.

Now i want if i scroll nav in second screen (yellow) then dot and hover tool tip background color change to different color.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    
    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 800, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center li').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before{box-sizing:border-box;}
body {box-sizing:border-box; margin:0px; padding:0 0 300px;}
section {height: 300px; margin: 1px; background: red;}
section.one{background:#fff;}
section.two{background:#ff0;}
ul {position: fixed; right:50px;}
li {list-style: none; width: 15px; height: 15px; position:relative; display:block;}
li a {
 display: block; 
 width: 14px; 
 height: 14px; 
 background:transparent; 
 border-radius:100%; 
 border:1px solid #ccc; 
 color: white; 
 text-decoration: none;
 }
li a.active, li a:hover {background: #000;}
li span{display:none;}
li:hover span{display:block; position:absolute; top:0px; left:-68px; background:#000; color:#fff; width:50px; height:18px; line-height:18px; padding:0 4px; font-size:13px;}
li:hover span::before {
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid #000;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  right: -8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-center">
  <li class="test"><a href="#test" data-scroll="top"></a><span>First</span></li>
  <li class="test2"><a href="#test2" data-scroll="news"></a><span>Second</span></li>
  <li class="test3"><a href="#test3" data-scroll="products"></a></li>
</ul>
<section class="one" id="test">1</section>
<section class="two" id="test2">2</section>
<section class="one" id="test3">3</section>
```

help me with example How to change background color nav dot and on hover tool tip background color when i scroll page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your jsfiddle code. Please this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yzq9zz9n/11/

I have add css and jquery when a tag has active class.
CSS:

```
li.test2 a.active{ background:red}
li.test3 a.active{ background:green}
li.test2.active:hover span{
  background:red;
}
li.test2.active:hover span:before{
  border-left-color:red;
}
li.test3.active:hover span{
  background:green;
}
li.test3.active:hover span:before{
  border-left-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try " + " sign for multiple li hover css like below for yellow color:

Only change the color what you have want:

CSS:

```
li + li:hover a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
li + li:hover span::before {
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid yellow;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
}
li + li:hover > span {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
li + li + li:hover a {
  background-color: black;
}
li + li a.active, li + li a:hover {
  background: yellow none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
li + li + li a.active, li + li + li a:hover {
  background: black none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

SEE [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yzq9zz9n/15/)

Comment: Thanks @Jainam for your solution but 1 thing more if i scroll to next 3rd slide then dot color same as first black but on hover toll tip color not change to black why?

Comment: if you have want first dot color black so is it okey, But you can change third dot color or hover color change you can apply li + li + li a:hover, for active li + li + li a.active, li + li + li a:hover or change span hover background color you can apply this li + li + li:hover > span .

Comment: if you have multiple li so you can increase like this li + li + li + li a:hover.

Answer (score 0):

You should selector to `a` element:

```
$('#menu-center a').each(function () {
 //...
})
```

Not `#menu-center`:

```
$('#menu-center').each(function () {
 //...
})
```

For the Third navigation, you miss tooltip text, update to:

```
<li class="test3"><a href="#test3" data-scroll="products"></a><span>Third</span></li>
```

This is code updated: [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/WorkWe/yzq9zz9n/16/)